# firebase with nodejs Error creating user:

Tags: firebase-authentication

I have the below error ... when i try to create a nue user with firebase in nodejs . I was activated de authentication in firebase console but nohting works for me.

i am using this link of docs:
https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/createuser.html

Error creating user: { [Error: The specified authentication provider is not enabled for this Firebase.]
  code: 'AUTHENTICATION_DISABLED',
  details: 'Projects created at console.firebase.google.com must use the new Firebase Authentication SDKs available from firebase.google.com/docs/auth/' }

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using the documentation for 'old' Firebase to set up a connection to a 'new' Firebase environment. I was having the same problem. The answer is in the error message - take a look at the docs at the new Firebase Authentication SDK as things have changed. Or, alternatively, create an environment using the old Firebase (www.firebase.com) and the documentation you are referencing should work. (Not sure how long before the 'old' Firebase is deprecated, though.)

Answer (score 0):

This error was produced becouse we cant authenticate from server side ,
"auth" is only allowed for client side,
i am working with an android app , and i create a new user from android , it works , my server side with node only conects with firebase for listening changes in database (firebase) .

Thanks for the observation.. and best regards